# Can I host a website locally without Internet

Tags: web, server, web-hosting, lamp

I want to host a website on a laptop without Internet. This laptop is running Ubuntu, MongoDB, and lamp. The when the website is hosted I want to connect a bunch of tablets to the website over USB. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can host the website but it will be accessible from the laptop only or same network. You can create a simple node js server and perform any CRUD operations using MongoDb.